# Keeping track of web site configuration details, action items, documentation?

Tags: documentation, tracking

Does anyone know of an application (hosted or otherwise) that I could use to keep track of details for a number of web sites?  I manage 50+ web sites that range from custom solutions to open source platforms (WordPress, Joomla).  I started to write my own but wanted to see if there is anything out there already.

Here are some of the features that I would like:

- Be able to keep track of the latest version of software so I know which sites need to be updated when patches are available.
- I would like to add tasks to remind me of period maintenance items that need to be performed.
- Add notes about the site.  (documentation, feature requests, etc)

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either Backpack or Highrise from [37 Signals](http://37signals.com) to track each project individually (e.g. creating tasks, milestones, notes, even documentation using writeboard). These are more of project managers and intranet-type software, so I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. I love their products, they are very easy to use and have a trim feature set that allows you to accomplish your tasks without being buried under a mountain of features. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific application that does what you're describing. However, Joomla! has a email-based release notification system set up that you could hook into: http://www.joomla.org/download.html

There should be an RSS feed behind this, but I can't find it at the moment.